# executable files to normal files via terminal CentOS7

Tags: permissions, executable, chmod

Today I copied some files from the shared folder (Host is a `Win7`) to my VM ( Guest is a `CentOS7`). I did this with root permissions. Then I copied th files to my apache location 
`/var/www/html/test` 
I am using putty, I only see the files in green and with the following permissions.

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 175417 Mar 15 17:50
```

I need to change the file from executable files (Green) to normal files should i use `chown` or `chmod` and with which extensions?
The files would be placed on a webside and should be downloadable.

to be clear i copied only a .zip file from `Win7` to `CentOS7`

Comment: `chmod 644 *.zip` for readable (by everyone) or `chmod a-x *.zip` to only remove the exec bits (but that's not readable by everyone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being executable is a type of mode. `chmod` **ch**anges **mod**es. `chown` **ch**anges **own**ers (ie. the user that owns this file, which has the mode bits with the highest magnitude).

As such all you need to do is `chmod a-x <path>` to remove the executable bit for all ("a") users. If you just wanted to do it for your user, the owner ("o"), you can use `o-x`. instead.

Comment: dear chris thank you, the problem was solved by comment above.

chmod 644 *.zip for readable (by everyone) or chmod a-x *.zip to only remove the exec bits (but that's not readable by everyone).